Help understanding circular permutation with restrictions
I need some help understanding a bit the intuition behind circular permutations and the inclusion–exclusion principle in practice.
Let's suppose there is a circular table for seven people.
If a pair that cannot sit alongside, the number of possible settings for this table would be: $(6)!-2*5!$ (the total settings for a table for seven would be $(7-1)!$, so it would be the difference to the settings that these two sit together). Thus, for a trio that cannot sit together, $(6)!-C(3,2)*4! = 6! - 3*4!$.
Now, what if there are three pairs or two trios that cannot sit together? (In the later case, I also guess it may not be possible for the size of the table)
For three pairs, I would guess something as $(6)!-6*5!+2^3 * 4! = 96$, being $2^3$ the permutations of each pair $(a,b)$, $(c,d)$, $(e,f)$, and $4!$ settings for each "block" $((a,b), (c,d), (e,f), (g))$. (edit: here I was thinking of two pairs, that would be $(6)!-2*(2*5!)+2^3 * 4!$, being $2!*2!*2!*4!$ the ways both pairs would sit together)
For two trios, then, would it be $(6)!-2*3*4!+2^2*3!$? (a very larger number than I would expect.)
Many thanks in advance!

When you say a trio can't sit together,  do you mean "no two members of the trio can sit together" or do you mean "the trio can't sit together as a group in any order"?  Assuming the latter,  I would think it mattered if the trios were disjoint or not.

Similarly with multiple pairs.

The trio can't sit together as a group, in any order (abc, acb, bac... forbidden). For the multiple pairs, (a,b) or (b,a), (c,d) or (d,c), (e,f) or (f,e), so a could sit with everyone except b.

also, in the case "no two members of the trio can sit together" wouldn't it be a variation of the three pairs case? the pairs (a,b), (a,c) and (b,c).

One pair cannot sit together
Your answer is correct; there are $6!-2\cdot 5!$ ways.
One trio cannot sit together
Your answer is incorrect. When counting the bad arrangements for which the triple is together, there are $3!$ ways the triple can be arranged consecutively. Then, there are four single people and one triple, so $5$ objects to be circularly arranged, which can be done in $(5-1)!=4!$ ways. Altogether, there are $6!-3!\cdot 4!$ circular arrangements where the triple is not together.
Three disjoint pairs cannot sit together
As you mentioned, we must use the principle of inclusion exclusion.
There are $6!$ arrangements, without any restriction. From these, for each pair, we must subtract the arrangements where that pair is together. There are $2\cdot 5!$ circular permutations where any particular pair is together, and three triples, so we subtract $3\times 2\cdot 5!$.
Next, we need to add back in the double intersections. When counting the arrangements where two particular pairs are together, there are $2^2\cdot 4!$ ways. The $2^2$ accounts for the order within both pairs, while $4!$ accounts for circularly arranging five objects (two pairs and three lone people). Since there are $\binom 32$ ways to choose two pairs, we add back in $\binom 32\times 2^2\cdot 4!$.
Finally, you must subtract the permutations with all three pairs adjacent. This means we subtract $\binom 33\times 2^3\times 3!$. The final answer is
$$
6!-3\times 2\cdot 5!+\binom 32 \times 2^2\cdot 4!-2^3\cdot 3!
$$
Two disjoint triplets cannot together
I will just give you the answer here. Try to use the previous solution as a template to solve this on your own, then check the answer below.

 $6! - 2\times 3!\cdot 4!+(3!)^2\cdot 2!$


Many thanks! I just added an edit that I confused the example with three pairs with the settings for two pairs that cannot sit alongside (that would be, then, 6! - 225! + 2^3 * 4!, if I understood it correctly).
